# Define variable in matlab

Tags: matlab

i want to define variable like x in Matlab but not a symbolic variable. this is an example of my code here i don't know how to define x except `syms x`:

`a=[1,2;3,4];
b=a-x*eye(2);
c=inv(b);`

really my program is very large and because of define x in `syms` speed of my program largely reduced i want to define x not in symbolic.

Comment: What do you expect from the code?

Comment: first we calculate matrix a then define b similar to above code then calculate inverse of b at this point we determine a matrix like d that make from component of c matrix. finally we define a matrix like e in form of `e=c*d*ctranspose(c)` at the end trace of e has been determined and getting integrate over variable x.

Comment: Okey , can't `x` vary over some values, like `x = 1 : 10`? and in a loop you do the stuff for each `x`.

Comment: yes x is a constant variable in all over the program only at the end of code we integrate of it.

Comment: x in the program do not change or equal to a number, only at the finall command integrating of it.

Comment: what is it like before the integration?

Comment: only a variable in matrix that have no rule only we define x to integrate over it.

Answer (score 0):

`syms` is a Symbolic Math Toolbox function that creates symbolic variables. Ordinary, non-symbolic variables in MATLAB are created dynamically, simply by assigning to them. For example, `x=0` creates a variable named `x` and assigns the scalar value `0` to it. You don't have to pre-declare x to be a variable; MATLAB figures it out by virtue of the name appearing on the left-hand side of an assignment statement.

Comment: x=0 is not a integrate-able variable so i can not use it.

Comment: If you want x to be integratable, it needs to by a symbolic variable, so it needs to be defined using syms. There aren't any other kinds of variables.

Comment: i think there is a numerical way.